# Fit gamma distribution to dataset with R

Tags: r, dataset, gamma-distribution

I have this dataframe below:

```
structure(list(x = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 48, 49, 50, 
51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 0, 
71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 4, 5, 6, 7, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 88, 89, 90, 91, 26, 27, 28, 14, 15, 16, 5, 6, 7, 
7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 1, 3, 29, 30, 0, 1, 20, 21, 22, 2, 3, 0, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 97, 98, 99, 100, 
101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 83, 16, 18, 19, 86, 87, 91, 92, 
93, 20, 21, 99, 100, 102, 103, 9, 10, 14, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
7, 11, 21, 63, 64, 65, 66, 3, 18, 19, 20, 21), y = c(1665.05355793238, 
2290.46808761358, 2479.44521586597, 1027.63470042497, 2382.83166897297, 
599.608228149824, 200.079963575583, 2715.53603386879, 2567.91178971529, 
2709.88102674484, 454.382090631872, 2268.14043972082, 2147.62290922552, 
2269.1387550775, 2247.31983098201, 1903.39138268307, 2174.78291538358, 
2359.51909126411, 2488.39004804939, 212.851575751527, 461.398994384333, 
567.150629704352, 781.775113821961, 918.303706148872, 659.580393221229, 
1107.37695799186, 1160.80594193377, 1412.61328924168, 1689.48879626486, 
650.35140038206, 280.949480787385, 641.231373456365, 412.116433330579, 
416.824746264203, 614.763061881065, 415.905685925856, 494.374217984441, 
201.745910386788, 486.030122926459, 647.782697262242, 269.898762604455, 
469.544556583467, 605.790549736819, 483.045965372879, 668.017897433514, 
35.2706101682852, 265.693628564011, 285.116345260642, 291.023782284086, 
357.428790589795, 205.920375034591, 229.606221692753, 230.952761338012, 
241.641164634028, 494.819531862799, 611.564698476112, 603.238720579422, 
524.322001078981, 565.296378873638, 532.431853589369, 597.174114277044, 
140.829281608807, 260.737164468854, 306.72700499362, 283.410379620422, 
366.813913489692, 387.570173754128, 648.038833109662, 606.075737104722, 
686.408686154056, 705.914347674276, 814.318649679422, 720.467501226114, 
897.123468788341, 1015.63389401929, 892.041182056069, 1587.7192387376, 
469.889315964654, 371.252178900875, 516.214449755847, 223.317826933191, 
233.990588575922, 254.111292146219, 388.602676983443, 477.858510450125, 
53.9083766029653, 128.198042456082, 521.591475207009, 535.519377609133, 
560.44362318865, 396.430340241175, 654.226210802794, 1303.48454248847, 
1274.19490102748, 1615.11958998814, 1445.12280311435, 1579.06517848652, 
1591.83073895803, 1926.41506405128, 2029.74201928871, 1762.10456025088, 
1093.34139243141, 998.179578598123, 980.315594917862, 1016.85559533851, 
996.357576390554, 1465.61544544157, 1639.27601695352, 3099.03079020977, 
3250.79935610294, 613.15010408836, 794.168323367026, 953.81404011324, 
1942.00127470493, 750.459735572338, 875.899619173259, 1166.28903575242, 
788.564458085224, 1324.95006324351, 1111.05266567506, 1020.29043261707, 
1130.40108603239, 1529.81020075083, 1480.88505926495, 524.398260936374, 
512.986586335697, 833.124012635089, 957.75556050241, 220.735156724928, 
584.620856728405, 1243.39788535796, 1578.20351953804, 1386.65165398503, 
906.813018662913, 798.186995701282, 831.365377249207, 764.519073183124, 
672.076289062505, 669.879217186302, 1388.61752325296, 1104.50366285443, 
1722.3172301054, 313.881701797247, 1217.21950829029, 1325.65616729856, 
2137.73167350888, 1958.17336059175, 2355.88909001648, 2261.16462984681, 
2499.84794190526, 908.743901610374, 1927.14038875327, 1880.97180615366, 
1977.65100651979, 1714.75837931037, 1265.48484068702, 1193.29000986667, 
1156.81486114406, 1199.7373066445, 1116.24029749935, 1141.89299393632, 
1545.56326286064, 1401.44881976186, 1346.97588634375, 1640.27575962036, 
1458.74134225518, 1102.85304791946, 1617.68811492418, 1380.66626644135, 
1614.92309916019, 1590.29306322336, 1516.55950581282, 1616.58492165804, 
785.721945669502, 1857.46475183964, 3546.82112717628, 3451.61194658279, 
2874.73860728741)), .Names = c("x", "y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(186L, 
187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 197L, 
198L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 206L, 207L, 208L, 209L, 
210L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 219L, 220L, 
221L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 228L, 229L, 230L, 231L, 
232L, 233L, 234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 241L, 242L, 
243L, 244L, 245L, 246L, 247L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 251L, 252L, 253L, 
254L, 255L, 256L, 257L, 258L, 259L, 260L, 261L, 262L, 263L, 264L, 
265L, 266L, 267L, 268L, 269L, 270L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 274L, 275L, 
276L, 277L, 278L, 279L, 280L, 281L, 282L, 283L, 284L, 285L, 286L, 
287L, 288L, 289L, 290L, 291L, 292L, 293L, 294L, 295L, 296L, 298L, 
299L, 301L, 302L, 303L, 304L, 305L, 306L, 307L, 308L, 309L, 310L, 
311L, 312L, 313L, 314L, 315L, 316L, 317L, 318L, 319L, 320L, 321L, 
322L, 323L, 324L, 325L, 327L, 328L, 329L, 330L, 334L, 335L, 336L, 
337L, 338L, 339L, 340L, 341L, 342L, 343L, 344L, 345L, 346L, 347L, 
348L, 349L, 350L, 351L, 352L, 353L, 354L, 355L, 356L, 357L, 358L, 
359L, 360L, 361L, 362L, 363L, 364L, 365L, 366L, 367L, 368L, 369L, 
370L))
```

I want to fit a gamma distribution to this dataset. I am trying to use this function `rgamma(n=, shape =, scale= )`. However I do not quite understand the way to compute the different parameters of the gamma distribution. I am quite a dummy in this and the examples I have seen so far do not really explain how to get the `shape` and `scale` values. Can someone give me some insights on it?

Comment: This is a bivariate dataset, whereas a Gamma distribution is univariate only. What, then, do you mean by "fit a gamma distribution" to it?  And why do you want to do that?

Comment: +1 to the comment above. Also the rgamma function generates random values from the gamma distribution so that would not be the function you would want to "fit" the data.

Comment: Well if you plot y against x, it looks like the pattern of my data follows a gamma function. So, I am trying to compute the different parameters of the gamma function which could fit my set of data. Do you have a better approach i could do that?

Comment: Non-linear curve fitting is one approach; see the `nls` package in R as an example.

Comment: What you are really asking, then, is how to fit a function of the form $y = A x^k\exp(-x)$ to your $(x,y)$ data.  The Gamma distribution appears to have nothing to do with it. What is more relevant is how you need to assess the goodness of fit.  If these points don't exactly line up along one of those curves, why would that occur? What is the source and nature of the variability that could produce such discrepancies?

Comment: I plotted the data.  There is no aspect of the $(x,y)$ data that looks remotely like a Gamma-shaped curve.  The *distribution* of $y$ might possibly have a Gamma shape.  If that's what you want to fit, then it would be best to eliminate the superfluous $x$ variable from your example. In any event, it's essential that you edit this question to clarify what you're trying to do, so that people don't get frustrated trying to figure out what you need.

Comment: A simple `plot(A$x, A$y)` (where `A` is your structure) shows that you may have some left-tail dependance, but nothing about the shape of the bivariate distribution. Yes, the very "uppermost" points in that plot seem to "trace" out the classic shape of a right-skewed density, but that doesn't mean anything; it's an optical illusion. $y$ itself *may* be gamma (see below in the answer and comments). Marginal $x$ certainly is not (it's bimodal).

Answer (score 9):

## Please see update section below for clarification based on OP comments made whilst this answer was being posted.

In general, the standard gamma distribution has two parameters, a **shape** paramemeter and a **scale** or **rate** paramemeter, where rate = 1 / scale. `R` help for `rgamma` uses shape as the canonical form; using that, with a gamma density defined as:

$$
\large f(x) = \frac{x^{\alpha - 1}e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}}{\theta^\alpha \Gamma(\alpha)}
$$

$\alpha$ is the **shape** parameter and $\theta$ is the **scale** parameter. The mean of the distribution is $\alpha\theta$ and the variance is $\alpha\theta^2$.

The simplest way to fit would be using the [Method of Moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_moments_%28statistics%29). Calculate the mean and variance of your data. Now you have two equations ($\hat{\mu} = \alpha\theta, \hat{\sigma}^2 = \alpha\theta^2$) so you can solve for $\alpha$ and $\theta$.

The other most common technique is tp use [maximum likelihood estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood). That would require using a non-linear optimizer (like `optim` or `nloptr`) to solve for the parameters which minimimze the negative log-likelihood, which you could get using `dgamma` with `log = TRUE`.

You could set up a function like so:

```
GammaNLL <- function(pars, data){
  alpha <- pars[[1]]
  theta <- pars[[2]]
  return (-sum(dgamma(data, shape = alpha, scale = theta, log = TRUE)))
}
```

and pass that into `nloptr` as

```
Fit <- nloptr(x0 = c(guess1, guess2), eval_f = GammaNLL, lb = c(0,0), data = data,
              opts = list(algorithm = "NLOPT_LN_SBPLX", maxeval = 1e5))
```

`Fit$solution` will have your MLE estimates.

In your particular case, however, your observations are pairs, so either you need to fit a multivariate distribution, which is less simple, or you want to fit the gamma to $x$ and $y$ independantly, which can be done using either method above.

Hope that helps.

## Update based on clarifications in question.

Plotting $y$ against $x$ looks as such `plot(A$x, A$y, pch =16)`:

[image]

The fact that the "top" lookes vaguely like a gamma is irrelevant; this is a scatter plot, not a density.

A kernel-smoothed density estimates of the marginal of $y$ *may* indicate a gamma (or some other right-skewed distribution) `plot(density(A$y, kernel = 'e'))`:

[image]

$x$ is bimodal, so it's marginal is certainly not gamma `plot(density(A$x, kernel = 'e'))`:
[image]

So I think you need to re-formulate your question more like "is there a reasonable way to fit a relationship between $x$ and $y$"

Comment: This approach is hopeless: because the integral is much greater than $1$, the data do not represent points on a Gamma distribution at all and no Gamma density function comes anywhere close to such a set of values.

Comment: @whuber The marginal $y$ can be fit using either method (MoM gives $\theta \approx 508.9, \alpha \approx 2.17$; MLE: $\theta \approx 546.2, \alpha \approx 2.02$). The $x$ values are clearly  bimodal though, so any fit wouldn't be good, although MoM **will** give an answer, simply due to algebra. I did say the method wouldn't work if there was a need for a multivariate fit.

Comment: For clarification, please read the OP's comments to the question.

Comment: @whuber They must have been added as I was answering, as the question was pristine when I started. Do you suggest deleting this answer?

Comment: I think some kind of modification would be needed to get the answer to match the question and the data.  It is indeed frustrating to see a question changed while you're writing out an answer.  That's why it's always a good idea to ask for clarification if you're uncertain about the interpretation or to wait for a response after a clarification has been requested. One thing you might do is delete the answer so that people don't downvote it--you can undelete it later if it turns out to be exactly what the OP was looking for.

Comment: Thanks; Instead I added an update section explaining why I think the OP needs to reformulate the question.